# Tapestry: Failure reading parameter 'test' of component :if

Tags: java, tapestry

I have `FindMyBids.java` and `FindMyBids.tml` but I got the next error:

> Caused by:
>   org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueException: Render
>   queue error in BeginRender[search/FindMyBids:if]: Failure reading
>   parameter 'test' of component search/FindMyBids:if:
>   org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException [at
>   classpath:es/udc/subasta/web/pages/search/FindMyBids.tml, line 7]

```
@AuthenticationPolicy(AuthenticationPolicyType.AUTHENTICATED_USERS)
public class FindMyBids {
    private final static int BIDS_PER_PAGE = 10;

    private int startIndex = 0;
    private Bid bid;
    private BidBlock bidBlock;

    @Property
    @SessionState(create = false)
    private UserSession userSession;
    @Inject
    private BidService bidService;
    @Inject
    private Locale locale;

    public Bid getBid() {
        return bid;
    }

    public void setBid(Bid bid) {
        this.bid = bid;
    }

    public List<Bid> getbids() {
        // System.out.println("ENTRA " + bidBlock.getBids().size());
        List<Bid> bids = bidBlock.getBids();
        return bids;
    }

    public Format getNumberFormat() {
        return NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
    }

    public Format getDateFormat() {
        return NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
    }

    public Object[] getPreviousLinkContext() {
        if (startIndex - BIDS_PER_PAGE >= 0) {
            return new Object[] { startIndex - BIDS_PER_PAGE };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Object[] getNextLinkContext() {

        if (bidBlock.getExistMoreBids()) {
            return new Object[] { startIndex + BIDS_PER_PAGE };
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    void onActivate(int startIndex) throws InstanceNotFoundException {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        bidBlock = bidService.findBidsByUserId(userSession.getUserProfileId(),
                startIndex, BIDS_PER_PAGE);
    }

    Object[] onPassivate() {
        return new Object[] { startIndex };
    }

}
```

This is FindMyBids.tml

```
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
    xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter" t:type="Layout" t:title="title"
    showTitleInBody="false">

<p class="text-center">${message:welcome}</p>

<t:if test="bids">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>${message:productName-label}</th>
                <th>${message:bidAmount-label}</th>
                <th>${message:winName-label}</th>               
                <th>${message:bidFecha-label}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr t:type="Loop" t:source="bids" t:value="bid">
                <td>
                    <a href="#" t:type="PageLink" t:page="search/productdetails"
                        t:context="bid.product.productId">
                        ${bid.product.name}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td><t:output value="bid.amount" format="NumberFormat"/></td>
                <td> ${bid.currentWinnerProduct.loginName}</td>
                <td><t:output value="bid.date" format="DateFormat"/></td>               
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>

    <!-- "Previous" and "Next" links. -->

    <ul class="pager">

        <t:if test="previousLinkContext">
            <li><a href="#" t:type="PageLink" t:page="search/findmybids"
                t:context="previousLinkContext">&larr; ${message:link-previous}</a></li>
        </t:if>

        <li>&nbsp;</li>

        <t:if test="nextLinkContext">
            <li><a href="#" t:type="PageLink" t:page="search/findmybids"
                t:context="nextLinkContext">${message:link-next} &rarr;</a></li>
        </t:if>

    </ul>

    <p:else>
        <h4 class="alert alert-danger text-center">${message:noBids}</h4>
    </p:else>

</t:if>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `test` parameter expects a `boolean` where you are returning a `List` from your `getBids()` method. Try this instead:

```
<t:unless test="bids?.empty">
   ...
</t:unless>
```

This is the opposite of `t:if` and by using `bids?.empty` you'll in effect call `bids == null || bids.isEmpty()`

Comment: I know that expect test parameter expected boolean but apidocs says that Tapestry has many built in coercions to boolean:
-String True if non-blank and not the literal string "false" (case insensitive)
-Number True if non-zero
Collection True if non-empty
Object True (as long as its not null)

Comment: @HMIACatracha I actually was not aware of the coercion for a non empty Collection. Personally I prefer clarity on what is going on and find using isEmpty() a lot more readable. I am not sure what is going on exactly. Do you have more of the stack trace available? And also, does my proposed solution solve your problem?